# zend framework form not showing

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, zend-framework

i am getting started with zend framework.I have encountered this problem with forms.
when opening localhost/item/create in browser, only the hello is shown, form isn't rendered.

what i did:
i created a controller in my project with `zf.sh create controller item`
then `zf.sh create action create item`.
Inside library folder, created App->forms->ItemEditor.php

```
    <?php

class App_forms_ItemEditor extends Zend_Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $email = $this->createElement('text', 'email');
        $email->setLabel('Your email address:');
        $email->setRequired(TRUE);
        $email->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress());
        $email->addFilters(array(
        new Zend_Filter_StringTrim(),
        new Zend_Filter_StringToLower()
        ));
        $email->setAttrib('size', 40);
        $this->addElement($email);

    }
}
```

declared its namespace in application.ini file

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "App_"
```

Inside views->scripts->item->create.phtml did this:

```
hello
<?php
echo $this->form->render();
?>
```

and then inside ItemController.php :

```
public function createAction()
    {
        $this->view->form=new App_forms_ItemEditor();
    }
```

only the hello is shown in the browser, rest of the form isnt shown. can anyone point out what i'm doing wrong.
thanks

Comment: Have you looked at html sources (in your browser)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the reason is that you overwriting Zend_Form::__constructor(). Forms that extend Zend_Form should use `init()` function to initialize their elements, not `__constructor()`.

Answer (score 3):

The best place to create your form elements is to override the `init()` method, eg

```
class App_forms_ItemEditor extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $email = $this->createElement('text', 'email');
        $email->setLabel('Your email address:');
        $email->setRequired(TRUE);
        $email->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress());
        $email->addFilters(array(
        new Zend_Filter_StringTrim(),
        new Zend_Filter_StringToLower()
        ));
        $email->setAttrib('size', 40);
        $this->addElement($email);

    }
}
```

If you hijack `Zend_Form::__construct()`, you should at least accept the same arguments and pass them on using `parent::__construct()`

Also, I'm a little unsure about the lowercase "f" in your class name's "form" part. From memory, the module autoloader translates a "Form" name part to a "forms" directory in your module.

I do note however that you're not using the module autoloader (or at least, you haven't shown that you are)

---

Regarding module autoloaders...

The bootstrap process registers a module autoloader using the configured `appnamespace` value (usually "Application") with base path "application".

A module autoloader automatically registers some class name / path mappings for classes starting with the configured namespace (eg "Application_"). This includes forms.

Basically, it means you can create forms under `application/forms/MyForm.php` with classname `Application_Form_MyForm` and the autoloader will find it.

Open up `Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader" to see the full list.

Comment: @Marcin This time it was my turn to include the code. You still beat me to the punch though ;)

Comment: you guys are awesome for such quick responses ! @Phil Brown can you elaborate the autoloader part please, i'm  a learner ;)